# Node.js CORS session cookie with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, cors

*I am making a simple login using Node.js with CORS and Angular.js.*

That is --- `client.example.com` is making a **POST** too `api.example.com/login` where on success a session cookie is returned too `client.example.com` and can gain access too a **GET** service like `api.example.com/secret` protected by the session cookie.

*Making GET requests that aren't protected by a session cookie isn't a problem.*

> Ultimately, the goal here is too [**authenticate a client side app to a REST api using CORS with a local stradegy**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286324/authenticate-client-side-app-too-rest-api-using-cors-with-local-stradegy) --- i.e. username & password --- even if the convention above isnt possible.

*I can not find a working implimentation to learn from anywhere --- point me in the right direction?*

***Bonus:*** Show a working example.

Comment: This is only possible if you set the domain of your cookie to be .example.com. You cannot set a cookie for client.example.com from api.example.com: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work

Comment: @alexwen What if I wanted to accept from any domain, like --- `client.example1.com` & `client.example2.com`. The goal here is too authenticate a client side app too a REST api using CORS with a local stradegy --- i.e. `username` & `password`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is very simple, browsers do not allow sending cookies set in one domain to be sent to a different domain.
This is for security. If your session cookie was accessible from any domain, then any site could perform csrf (by definition, what you want is to do csrf - use the session from one site in a different site).

There are ways around it, though you should be careful when applying them.

- Easiest way is by using Jsonp to login and make cross-domain requests, jsonp basically breaks the cookies cross-domain policies.
- You can embed an iFrame in `client.example.com` page that sits in `api.example.com`, the parent and the iFrame can communicate using [post message](http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage).

Both ways are open to csrf requests (by their very nature), so you should be extra careful in what information you allow `client.example.com` to access.