# Using a REST API and a Javascript client, how to stay logged in after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, cookies, passwords, client, store

Currently, my authentication flow is as follows:

1. User fills in a login form in the client browser app (AngularJS, to be precise), username and password are stored into the browser's memory (plain Javascript variables).
2. When accessing protected API resources, the request is authenticated with HTTP Basic Auth over SSL using the credentials stored in memory.

The problem is, **when the user refreshes the page, her credentials are wiped out and she needs to sign in again**. Am I missing something obvious here?

Few solutions I've found so far:

1. Store username and password into a cookie: this seems obviously insecure, even when using secure cookies and/or encryption.
2. Use session cookies: this seems to be against the RESTful principle of statelessness.

(I guess OAuth has the same problem with securely storing access tokens in the client?)

Comment: sessionStorage to the rescue

Comment: @dandavis "sessionStorage object does not persist if we close the tab", I don't think this is the solution.

Comment: oh, i thought you wanted that. refresh!= close tab... just use use localStorage instead.

Comment: @dandavis Isn't localStorage vulnerable to XSS injections just like cookies are? Thanks for the tip though, I'll have to read up on localStorage.

Comment: not anymore than variables are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16313669/2444808), I ended up doing something like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48166055/authflow.png) (link opens a rather large picture).

In short, client stores Access Token in a javascript variable, but Refresh Tokens are stored in a server-side session (on the server hosting our client app, not on the API server).

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies are totally fine here. Once installed you dont care of them, browser will send them with each request via headers.

Comment: Would the session exist in the API server or the server that hosts my browser-based app? I'd rather not have sessions on my API server, but the latter option might be possible. But don't the session cookies have security issues too?

Comment: Dont forget that api server have to exchange login/password for session token - token is the thing which you want to store in cookies.